# Using Excel context in Excel custom function

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I'm trying to use `var context = new Excel.RequestContext()` in an Excel custom function as specified in the documentation, but the browser keeps complaining the Excel object does not exist. Anyone managed to call Excel object functions from custom functions ?

Thanks
Matteo

Comment: Using Excel RequestContext in an Excel custom functions needs to config your Excel add-in to use a shared runtime. [Share data and events between Excel custom functions and the task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial) shows how to config an add-in to use shared runtime.